# How to use try catch nicely in multiple methods?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

Sorry if my question is stupid, but I have this kind of code :

```
public Object1 Method1(Object2 parameter)
{
    try
    {
        return this.linkToMyServer.Method1(parameter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.Logger(e);
    }

    return null;
}

public Object3 Method2(Object4 parameter)
{
    try
    {
        return this.linkToMyServer.Method2(parameter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.Logger(e);
    }

    return null;
}

/* ... */

public ObjectXX Method50(ObjectXY parameter)
{
    try
    {
        return this.linkToMyServer.Method50(parameter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.Logger(e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

I think you see the pattern. Is there a nice way to have only one try catch and to pass a generic method in this try catch ?

Instinctively I'd use a delegate, but delegates have to have the same signature right ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you see code like this you can apply [Template Method Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx).

May be something like this:

```
private TResult ExecuteWithExceptionHandling<TParam, TResult>(TParam parameter, Func<TParam, TResult> func)
{
    try
    {
        return func(parameter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.Logger(e);
    }
    return default(TResult);
}

public Object1 Method1(Object2 parameter)
{
    return ExecuteWithExceptionHandling(parameter, linkToMyServer.Method1);
}

public Object3 Method2(Object4 parameter)
{
    return ExecuteWithExceptionHandling(parameter, linkToMyServer.Method2);
}
```

And so on...

Comment: This, or just get a central point to manage the final handling of your exceptions; meaning, if you have to log a lot, you can catch them in your functions, and rethrow them to handle them in Main or else. Maybe mind throwing a new exception though, with the previous one as its InnerException property.

Comment: @Sriram, hey! Mind blowing code, I've implemented it in my custom pattern. But question: How to use that on voids and parameterless methods?
  
It causes this error: 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'BLLFactory.Execute<TParam, TResult>(TParam, Func<TParam, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Eli Hard to tell without looking at your code. For void methods you've to create another overload of your template method which takes `Action` as a parameter not `Func`. If you still can't get it working please create new question and optionally drop a link here.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful to you.

```
public object BaseMethod(object[] userParameters,String FunctionName)
{
  try
   {    
          Type thisType = this.GetType();
          MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(FunctionName);
          object returnObj;
          returnObj = theMethod.Invoke(this, userParameters);
          return returnObj;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
            this.Logger(e.InnerException);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One example of such central handling can be found from `chocolatey` open source git.

Centralization happens using two static public methods `FaultTolerance.try_catch_with_logging_exception` - for example user of this function would need to write something like this:

[ChocolateyPackageService.cs#L1073](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/67190e5408372176084351b895e0cb1d841cee69/src/chocolatey/infrastructure.app/services/ChocolateyPackageService.cs#L1073)

and there are two functions which handles this kind of call -

1. [With `Func` parameter](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/67190e5408372176084351b895e0cb1d841cee69/src/chocolatey/infrastructure/tolerance/FaultTolerance.cs#L159)
2. [With `Action` parameter](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/67190e5408372176084351b895e0cb1d841cee69/src/chocolatey/infrastructure/tolerance/FaultTolerance.cs#L130)

Other arguments to function are up to you to decide if you want to have them or not - they could adjust or log specific error message once exception occurs.

(All links are provided with absolute points in git history, so will not get broken in future).